# Как можно создать и заполнить List< Integer >[ ]?

Tags: java

Как можно создать и заполнить `List< Integer >[ ]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] arr = (ArrayList<Integer>[])new ArrayList[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list.add(<объект>);
```

С [сайта](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/arraylist.php):

> Метод `add()`
>
> Метод `add()` самый популярный и не требует особых
>   объяснений. Только не забывайте, что существует перегруженная версия
>   метода, позволяющая вставлять элемент в нужную позицию.
>
> `cats.add(2, new Cat("Рыжик"));`
>
> Следует быть осторожным, чтобы
>   ненароком не вставить в несуществующую позицию. По возможности,
>   избегайте операций вставки в середину коллекции. Ведь системе
>   приходится заново пересчитывать индексы элементов.

Comment: А как вообще создать List< Integer >[ ]?